# Is Darwin adopted?

Tags: amazing-world-of-gumball

Gumball (like his mum, Nicole) is a cat. Anais is a rabbit (like her dad,  Richard).

Darwin is a fish on legs.

Is he adopted? I can't find anything official. All I found was someone on [gamefaq.com](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/203-cartoons-and-animation/60297858) saying :

> He was Gumball's pet fish before he grew legs. That's why he sleeps in a fishbowl

The (unofficial) [wiki](http://theamazingworldofgumball.wikia.com/wiki/Darwin_Watterson) backs this up but gives no episodic reference. The closest it gets is saying that Darwin is Richard's favourite pet fish

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect *The Origins*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **Yes**

According to an this episode [The Origins](http://theamazingworldofgumball.wikia.com/wiki/The_Origins), he was originally a pet fish who was later adopted.

> When Mom and Dad struggle to keep hyperactive, toddler-aged Gumball from trashing the house and exhausting them, they decide to buy him a pet. It works, but there’s a problem: every goldfish they get him is short-lived, and inevitably ends up being flushed down the toilet. However, when **Dad buys a talking goldfish from a mysterious shop, Gumball meets the best friend he’ll ever have.** Having been accidentally flushed down the toilet, Darwin has to find his way back to his new family.

From the [transcript](http://theamazingworldofgumball.wikia.com/wiki/The_Origins:_Part_Two/Transcript)  we learn that he:

- Was bought and adopted by the Watersons:

> Narrator: [speaking very fast] But more importantly, The Wattersons have **adopted** a magical fish called Darwin who they love very much but... accidentally flush him down the toilet.
>
> Darwin: **No. They bought me** from a magic van.

- And that he grew legs:

> Darwin: **Ow! Huh? Ow! What? I've got legs**. Ahhh! What is happening to me? Ahhh! I can't run away from them! Wait a minute, I can't run at all. Elmore! Huh? It looks pretty small. Oh it's not small, it's really far away. How do people these things? There must be an easier way! All fours! That's better. Yes! I made it! Do you know where The Wattersons live? They have a son called Gumball, and he's my best friend. Do you know? He looks like this!

Temporarily, you can legally watch the episode for free [here](http://www.cartoonnetwork.com/video/gumball/the-origins-episode.html). You will need an account to watch the full episode.

Comment: Adopted implies some sort of adoption process happened, instead of him being a pet. This doesn't say anything different to the wiki I linked.

Comment: "Wikipedia (which is presumably held to higher standards by moderators)" ... all my college professors are slapping their heads in weary frustration.

Comment: @cybermike Edited.

Comment: @roguejedi I'll wait until this has been verified. It seems the wiki summary comes from [here](http://www.toonzone.net/forums/threads/cartoon-network-international-news-thread.4264941/page-937?_ga=1.26596157.1456072597.1446797063#post-84070422) which I can't verify.

Comment: The episode is out! Feel free to use parts of my answer in yours as you updated it.

Comment: @RogueJedi I'd improve this by adding a summary of your quotes, as it is, there's no conclusion. Also quotes from other episodes would also help.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Updated.

Comment: I love Darwin's name. A fish with legs: Evolution!! :D

Answer (score 10):

He's registered as a "pet fish", as shown by this dialog in episode 24, Genius where Darwin is taken away by the government.

> **Nicole**: What makes you think I'll let you take away my son?!
>
> **Principal Brown**: Well, technically you're not his parents. He's registered as a, "pet fish".

Later in "The egg" Nicole mentions he grew legs due to her parenting:

> **Nicole**: Ahaha, oh, you! This is Gumball and Darwin. Darwin used to be a goldfish, but through love, care and of course parenting skills became a goldfish with legs! Show 'em, sweety.

At no point does she say he's adopted though.

Answer (score 1):

In both "The Disaster" and "The Re-Run" it is officially stated that he is adopted. In the episode Rob puts evil magic subtitles on Gumball and they say to Darwin, "If we hadn't **adopted** him we would have enough money," and in "The Re-Run" they say, "We should have **adopted** somthing with more brains, like a carrot." Also in the episode "The Password," Gumball obviously tries to bring Darwin being adopted up without hurting his feelings. He says, "Because you’re not, when you look at it from a biological point of view, (cough) you know?" Obviously he was referring to him being adopted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they bought him from a pet shop... Remember Gumball's fish kept dying, finally they found Darwin and kept him. Only a true Gumball fan understands!